# Control Theory- Designing Cascade Lead Compensator

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I want to design lead compensator but phase margin is 75. I looked into some websites if phase margin is greater than 50 we have to design cascade two lead compensator. I need to find attenution factor  but i do not know how much i take phase margin to calculate attenution factor .Thanks for your helping

Comment: You are required to have 75° phase margin, or you already have that much phase margin? Usually related to feedback control "cascade" I believe refers to sequential loop closing, but I assume you are referring to a second order lead compensator?

Comment: I am required to have 75° phase margin but I do not supply only one compensator. I am referring about second order lead compensator. @KwinvanderVeen

Comment: But anything above 60° PM usually does not give any robustness gain. Or is this such that the closed loop system can handle a given maximum time delay?

Comment: It is not important to give robustness gain for now. I am just interested in supply to system greater than  50° phase margin. I want to know how to design cascade lead compensator via frequency domain. Do i have to design  all lead compensators are identical? If i am required to have 75° do I take as first compensator give 50° phase margin and second one give 25° phase margin.Maybe you can understand better when you look at this question?

Comment: The question From Richard Dorf:  P10.12 A unity feedback system has a plant
G{s) = 20/(s( 1+ 0.1s)(1 + 0.05s))
Select a compensator Gc(s) so that the phase margin
is at least 75°. Use a two-stage lead compensator
Gc(s) =(K(1+ s/w1)(i1+ s/w3))/((1 + s/w2)(1+ s/w4))
It is required that the error for a ramp input be 0.5%
of the magnitude of the ramp input (Kv = 200) @KwinvanderVeen